# Android + SMS Receiver + Toast = FAIL

Tags: android, toast

I am trying to get this code to work on my Dell Streak but when I receive an SMS I still dont get a Toast notification... I have added the 'receive' tag in the manifest.xml file... I am a complete noob at this and need a little help getting started :)

```
package net.learn2develop.SMSMessaging;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();       
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";           
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];           
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);               
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";       
            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }                         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create `Toast`s from non-UI components. You should only create `Toast`s from `Activity`s. The reason why the `Toast` isn't showing is because the `BroadcastReceiver` isn't running on a thread with a `Looper` and `Toast` depends on it, among other things that get setup for a UI thread. [`Notification`s](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) are meant for non-UI components to notify the user.